# Is it really the Power required for comparing input and output?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, switching-regulator

Hi I want to drive a 5W (5V*1A) output... Can it be carried by a 10W input (15V*0.670A) ? Is it just the power needed? Or should I need a larger current than 0.670A ?

Is this applicable for LDO Regulators or/and Switching Regulator?

Comment: Not applicable for any linear regulator, LDO or otherwise. But OK for any decent switcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The power output for any voltage regulator cannot exceed the power input. That's a fundamental rule of nature.

In the real world, the power out is less than the power in. The ratio of power out to power in is the **efficiency** of the regulator.

A switching regulator can have a higher output **current** if the output voltage is less than the input voltage, or can have a higher output **voltage** if the output current is less than the input current. However, a linear voltage regulator must have a higher input voltage than its output voltage **and** a higher input current than its output current. That means that the efficiency of a linear regulator is usually much lower than a switching regulator.

Answer (score 0):

Power-in to a voltage regulator equals power-out plus reglator losses.

If the regulator is linear then we can also reasonably say that: -

Current-in = current-out

If the input-voltage is 15 volts and the current is 1 amp, the input-power is 15 watts. The output-power is 5 watts and the losses in heat due to regulating the output are 10 watts.

For a switching regulator in the same scenario, the power efficiency is usually much higher and, as a first approximation you can say that power-out equals power-in hence your 15 volt supply would have to supply 333 mA.

As a 2nd (and improved) approximation, you can assume that a switching regulator is 90% efficient hence, power-in will be about 5.6 watts and, the current from the 15 volt input supply will be about 370 mA.